# How can I kill Zelkarons without the Silver chimes?

Tags: ys-origin

How can I kill Zelkarons without the Silver chimes? My understanding is I need to kill one while holding the Blue Necklace instead.

> This is apparently required to survive the charging of the Evil Ring required to bypass the Devil's Gaze.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to have the ring equiped at this stage, so you can switch to the chimes instead. You equip or unequip it from the inventory screen the same way you would equip the underwater breathing necklace or use the crystal or the shell. Equiped items have the blue background in their slot.

Killing the Zelkarons is a bit tougher matter, but it's just a question of hacking and slashing them for a bit, or gaining a level or two (or more) and returning.

Only AFTER the ring is charged you need to have the crystal necklace equiped not to die while putting on the ring.

Comment: The ring is in the inventory screen and I can't really equip or unequip it. My understanding is I must choose between the silver chimes (needed to kill the undead) and the blue necklace (needed to avoid the 9,999 damage).

Comment: Edited - yes, you can equip and unequip the items on the inventory screen.

Comment: "Only AFTER the ring is charged you need to have the crystal necklace equiped not to die while putting on the ring." ...but the ring charges immediately as I kill the third undead Zelkaron?

Comment: It does (or should), but it will kill you only if you equip the ring and don't equip the necklace. See this segment of a video: http://youtu.be/wfKbFuUKOUs?t=3m2s (starts roughly at 3:02)

Answer (score 0):

You can't: you have to use the silver chimes. My understanding is I need to kill one while holding the Blue Necklace instead is wrong:

> There actually are a couple of seconds between the "Evil Ring has charged" message and the 9,999 damage that kills you. If you open the menu immediately after the message appears and equip the Blue Necklace, you will not take damage.